# Merge 2 csv files to one for multiple files

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have 200 files in 2 parts. eg. (*aapl-BAL-Q.csv* and *aapl-CAS-Q.csv*) and I merged them to **aapl-ALL.csv** with pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
a = pd.read_csv('.../aapl-BAL-Q.csv')
b = pd.read_csv('.../aapl-CAS-Q.csv')
c = pd.concat([a,b], join='outer', axis=0, ignore_index=True, join_axes=None)
c.to_csv('...aapl-ALL.csv', index=False)
```

now I need to do it for the rest of files (eg. *aa-BAL-Q.csv* and *aa-CAS-Q.csv*) and so on.. I'm wondering how do that easiest way, instead of renaming filenames in code, tnx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can:

1. read all files into a pandas.Series using `pathlib.Path('/path/to/data_dir').glob('*.csv')`
2. group that series by first part of filename
3. read all CSV files belonging to each group

   - concatenate them
   - save concatenated DF to CSV file

---

```
from pathlib import Path

p = Path(r'/path/to/data/directory')

files = pd.Series([f.name for f in p.glob('*.csv')])

(files.groupby(files.str.split('-').str[0])
      .apply(lambda g: pd.concat([pd.read_csv(p / f) for f in g], ignore_index=True)
                         .to_csv(p / (g.name.split('-')[0] + '-ALL.csv'), index=False)))
```